# PHP require() or include() stops the script without errors

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface, require

I have this code:

```
echo "1 - is_readable: " . is_readable("/var/www/docroot/wp-load.php") . "\r\n";
echo "2 - file_exists: " . file_exists("/var/www/docroot/wp-load.php") . "\r\n";
echo "3 - before require\r\n";
require("/var/www/docroot/wp-load.php");
echo "4 - after require\r\n";
```

But the output is strange:

```
1 - is_readable: 1
2 - file_exists: 1
3 - before require
```

> This situation appears when I start script from CLI or CRON, when I
> start it directly in browser - all is fine.

What is happened echo 4 doesn't display?
Also I've tried to require another file, result is the same.

upd. task in crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * root php -f /mypath/fetch_data.php >> /mypath/results.out.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Depending on the platform you are on the PHP ini file being used from the command line and the one being used by the browser may be different.

Comment: I've already turned on all the errors displaying, but its are absent

Comment: In browser php code runs under `www-data` (depends on what is you web server of course, but by default it is a `www-dada` user most of times). What user do you use to run cron script? Also there is an [open-basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) which can be different for web and cli contexts.

Comment: If `exit` or `die` is called it will terminate the parent script without error. And looks like wp-load does call the function `wp_die`. Try echoing out $die and then replacing `wp_die` with `return` in wp-load.php and you should be able to see the output then. (don't forget to revert this after figuring out what the error is)

Comment: So fetch data works from browser? If yes then why not just setup the CRON using a curl command to the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `wp-load.php` file. It has below line

```php
error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
```

This basically disables all the error reporting that you want. So edit the file and comment it and add

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then you will know what the issues is. Also not all php files are compatible with CLI as they use some code that may only be valid when running under a web context.

So if you are not able to fix the error in CLI, you can run the curl call to do the migration

```
*/1 * * * * root curl http://localhost/path/to/url
```

Issue with this is that you will not get logs but only the output that your script gives. Also in case your scripts runs for long then you will need to add `set_time_limit(0)`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

The script may be already included and is producing an error on the second inclusion. Try `require_once()` instead.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php